# How to check that the data is 'null' in django view?

Tags: python, django, validation, view, null

I have a small validation to do in my view,i have to check whether the data received from the data field (for which'null'=true) of the form is null or not.
Presently i did this by

```
if data_received == None :
                    "some task"
```

and i got what i wanted.
My question is
Is this code optimum or there is some better way to do the same.

Comment: condition should be `if data_received`:

Comment: @avasal That's not equivalent. It won't give the same result if `data_received` is false in a boolean context.

Comment: `if data_received is None:` is preferable..

Comment: @avasal It also won't give the same result of data_received is equal to 0.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's pretty much as good as it's going to get. You typically want to use `is None` instead of `== None` just in case the left hand side is an instance of a class which has defined `==` to mean something special when used with `None`, but it's not a big deal here.

Answer (score 6):

**is None** used for *== null*   and  **is not None** used for *!=null*

Answer (score 0):

That's the best way I can think of doing it.  If your pulling data that might be Null in Django from an SQL server then you might have a bottleneck in actually pulling that data.